# Converting a C struct into Python to be sent through a socket

Tags: python, sockets, struct, swig, ctypes

I'm currently updating an old, large piece of software written in C that sends a struct through a socket to a server.  The updated software will be written in Python, which means I now need to send the same information in the same byte layout as the C struct in Python.  I'm aware of the Python package struct, and would like to use it. The problem is, the struct is absolutely huge.  To give you an idea, here's a snipet:

```
// this is the struct that I wish to send 

typedef struct
{
    struct st_command_header header;

    union {
        char buffer[32];
        struct set_360_camera_message camera_msg;
        struct u_olcd_msg olcd_msg;
    };   

} struct_to_be_set stc;


// supporting structs

struct st_command_header
{
  union  u_all_types len;
  union  u_all_types cmd;
  union  u_all_types cmd_counter;
  union  u_all_types items;
} __attribute__((packed));

struct u_olcd_msg
{  
  // over 100 lines of fields to fill
}

// all the other structs necessary
```

As I understand it, the struct python package requires you manually pack the struct, which would be very difficult given the size of the struct and number of union statements.  Ideally, I'd like some way to utilize the existing code by generating the struct in C but somehow transferring over the bytes to my Python code for the socket.  Is there a way to do this?  I have looked into ctypes and swig, but I didn't see an easy way to get the byte representation from the C code.

Comment: [cffi](https://cffi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Comment: thanks JBernardo, that looks helpful.  Is there an easy way to access the byte representation?

Comment: I am looking for a solution as well.  Mind sharing your finding?